# AngularJS example in backbone.js and/or knockout.js

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, knockout.js, javascript-framework

I'm comparing these frameworks to do some calculations on the client side. I really liked the example on the [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) site. I was wondering if any of the backbone.js or knockout.js experts on the site would please recreate that example in their respective frameworks.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IgorMinar/PV53g/%22%3Ehttp://jsfiddle.net/IgorMinar/PV53g/) for it.

Code of the Fiddle:

```
<table ng:init="invoice= {items:[{qty:10, description:'gadget', cost:9.95}]}">
  <tr>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng:repeat="item in invoice.items">
    <td><input name="item.qty" value="1" size="4" ng:required ng:validate="integer"></td>
    <td><input name="item.description"></td>
    <td><input name="item.cost" value="0.00" ng:required ng:validate="number" size="6"></td>
    <td>{{item.qty * item.cost | currency}}</td>
    <td>[<a href ng:click="invoice.items.$remove(item)">X</a>]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href ng:click="invoice.items.$add()">add item</a></td>
    <td></td>
    <th>Total:</th>
    <td>{{invoice.items.$sum('qty*cost') | currency}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
<!-- 
  Workaround for jsfiddle to pass in ng:autobind
  http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#css
-->
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-0.9.10.min.js" ng:autobind></script>

<style>
table th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
table td {
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

Comment: anybody from the backbone.js community want to give it a shot please. would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go for knockoutjs >

http://jsfiddle.net/neebz/YbwzJ/

I might be biased but it's a lot more structural than angular/backbone.

If you have any questions, let me know.

There are some NaN checks which I think you could take yourself.

Comment: that was fast, thank you. i didn't mention that because the angular example made sense to me (a truly novice programmer) i can compare the frameworks and pick one to start with. thanks again

Comment: one area in which knockout really loose backbone or angular is validation and in your example you also doesn't have it.

Comment: that's true. I usually use jQuery validate plugin for validation along with knockoutjs.

Comment: fiddle fails to load (in Chrome:"ko is not defined") and IMHO knockout is far too verbose

Comment: @nEEbz you should seriously try angular.. The structure and terseness of the code is really evident..

Comment: :( tutorial on jsfiddle is broken

Comment: is it fixed under a different fiddle? Cuz the one you've got posted still throws an error.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell : apparently jsfiddle forked it out > http://jsfiddle.net/neebz/YbwzJ/46/

Answer (score 21):

Also have a look https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc which show a standard TODO app written in all popular frameworks.